# Algorithm of a complement graph using adjacency matrix

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, pseudocode, complement

How to implement a complement graph which is given with adjacency matrix (literally any graph)?

I am wondering how to make a code of that graph, but I am not sure how to complete it.

I usually use pseudocode for these "early" implementations. This is what I have come up so far,
it is just the beginning of the code. I know how to draw the complement graph, I know it's definitions, but I struggle with finishing it with the code.

```html
Complement (G,s)
int Arr[1...size(V)]
queue Q
  for i=1 to size(V)
    Arr[i]=0
```

Comment: By replacing *0 with 1* and *1 with 0* in the adjacency matrix. To avoid self loops, all the elements of the *main diagonal* should be set 0.

Comment: @AKSingh of course, I thought of the same thing but don't know how to transfer my thoughts into code. Do I need two arrays then, two for loops or just one? Thank you for your answer though!

Comment: I can provide you with pseudocode. I use java. If you want solution in that, I can do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is to find the *complement of a graph*. Its solution depends on the representation of graph used. In the question you have mentioned that *adjacency matrix* will be used to represent the graph.

### Pseudocode

---

Here is a function which takes a *graph* as *input* and *outputs* the *complement graph*. Both the graph are represented using adjacency matrix.

```
G = Graph
G.V = graph vertices
CG = complement graph   

Complement(G)
       
1: for i = 0 to G.V
2:     for j = 0 to G.V
3:         if i == j: continue
4:         if G[i][j] = 0: CG[i][j] = 1             
5:         else CG[i][j] = 0   
6:           
7: return CG
```

---

Comment: thank you sir. Just as I imagined. You helped me and solved the question!